# unable to loop on ansible_Devices dictionary

Tags: ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Team,

not sure what is missing in my task as it complains it is not a dictionary. below is my error, sample output and task included. appreciate the help. thanks

output

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "with_dict expects a dict"}
```

task

```
- name: looping
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }}"
  when: "not {{ item.value.partitions }}"
  with_dict: hostvars[inventory_hostname]["ansible_devices"]
```

my output looks like this below so is my above task right way to loop?

```
ok: [node] => {
       "hostvars[inventory_hostname][\"ansible_devices\"]": {
           "loop0": {
               "holders": [],
               "host": "",
               "links": {
                   "ids": [],
                   "labels": [],
                   "masters": [],
                   "uuids": []
               },
               "model": null,
               "partitions": {},
               "removable": "0",
               "rotational": "1",
               "sas_address": null,
               "sas_device_handle": null,
               "scheduler_mode": "none",
               "sectors": "0",
               "sectorsize": "512",
               "size": "0.00 Bytes",
               "support_discard": "0",
               "vendor": null,
               "virtual": 1
           },
    "loop1": {
               "holders": [],
               "host": "",
               "links": {
                   "ids": [],
                   "labels": [],
                   "masters": [],
                   "uuids": []
               },
               "model": null,
               "partitions": {},
               "removable": "0",
               "rotational": "1",
               "sas_address": null,
               "sas_device_handle": null,
               "scheduler_mode": "none",
               "sectors": "0",
               "sectorsize": "512",
               "size": "0.00 Bytes",
               "support_discard": "0",
               "vendor": null,
               "virtual": 1
           }
}
```